# Partial mocking of a class

Tags: java, unit-testing, powermockito

Class Under Test:

```
public class A {
    public static String m1(String p1, String p2);

    public static String m2(String p1, String p2, Object p3) {
        //...other work involving p3
        String res;
        if(conditionA)
        {
            res = m1(p1,p2); 
        } else {
            res = //something else;
        }
        //continue work
    }
}
```

Details:
Method m1 makes a database call, with "inherent" (not injected) dependencies on Hibernate and Configs.
There're existing consumers of methods m1 and m2, so changing the signature is not an option. m1/m2 did not have tests written already.

conditionA is a remotely "controlled" launch gate (which i'm able to mock).

The if condition is what I've added recently, and need to verify the behaviour of method m2 under both values of conditionA.

What I'm looking for is a way to provide a mock implementation of m1, while still calling the real method m2.

Whatever I try to do to mock m1, I'm always ending up with unfinished stubbing exception from PowerMockito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First method: Mockito

You should do partial mocking. With mockito, you can do:

`A a = Mockito.spy(A.class);`

Then you can stub the method you want mocked like this:

`Mockito.doReturn("result").when(a).m1(...);`

The other method will remain the real one.

#### Second method: PowerMockito

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
when(A.m1(...)).thenReturn("result");
```

Once again, the other method will remain the real one.

Comment: Will this pattern also work with powermockito? Asking since these methods are static and mockito doesn't  allow static mocks...

Comment: Thanks a lot NiVeR. I figured out the PowerMockito way and ended up going with it